# Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0 or Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0

Tags: xml, com, vbscript, msxml

I have a VBScript COM Component where I'm using Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0 however is there / will there be any benefit from using Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0

I played with it a bit on a local machine and saw minor performance improvements using 6.0 however I couldn't find any good reference on the web relating to any possible gotcha's

Does anyone else have any tips / pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tests, with your data aren't showing a compelling improvement, then it doesn't really matter - for you - what anyone else has seen...

That said, you may want to upgrade simply to get it over with. You'll probably have to sooner or later anyway...

Comment: It looks like it hasn't made any difference so I took the approach of just upgrading now, rather than later.